# Could not read from remote repository when pushing to Heroku (Rails Tutorial 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I pushed my chapter 5 version of Sample_App to git, and then when I 'git push heroku' I get:

```
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

git config --global push.default simple

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)


!  No such app as sample_app.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have read through some of the similar stackoverflow questions, and so I know to look at the 'git remote -v':

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:sample_app.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:sample_app.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:jeffbenner/sample_app.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:jeffbenner/sample_app.git (push)
```

I have tried removing heroku and re-pushing - I get the same error message.

I looked at 'git config -l':

```
user.name=jeffbenner
user.email=xxxxx@gmail.com
alias.co=checkout
push.defaults=simple
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=false
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:jeffbenner/sample_app.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
remote.heroku.url=git@heroku.com:sample_app.git
remote.heroku.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
```

I cannot figure out why I cannot push to Heroku. I have re-logged into both my Github and Heroku accounts through the CLI. Any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this your first time pushing to heroku? when you run the command `git status' what does it say?

Comment: It's not the first time I have pushed. 

'git status' says:

    # On branch master
    # Changes not staged for commit:
    #   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
    #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    #
    # deleted:    app/views/layouts/applications.html.erb
    # modified:   spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
    #
    no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: ok just want to see what branch you were on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to specify the branch that you are pushing. Try `git push heroku master`. You can read about the [warning in the docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config.html). Let me know if it worked

Edit

I would just start over all together and create a new Heroku address. Follow these steps in order

First in your `Gemfile` create these groups

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Important, make sure you are in the `root` of your `project` and make sure you run `bundle install` like this

```
bundle install --without production
```

now `git add .` then `git commit -m 'your commit message'`

now run `heroku login` from the command line

now run `heroku create`

then `git push heroku master`

finally `heroku open` will open your app in your browser

If all of this doesn't work then move the app into a new directoy and start all over by first `git init`, `git add .` and `git commit -m 'first commit in new location'` and follow the steps above starting with `heroku login`

Note that heroku and github both use git but are independent entities. If you can push your code to github and you see it on github, then you should be able to push your code to heroku with no problem. If not you may be doing something wrong with git locally on your computer.

Comment: `git push heroku master` yields:

`
 !  No such app as sample_app.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: what is the URL to your heroku app?

Comment: From surveying my previous apps on Heroku, it does not look like I have ever successfully pushed a commit of sample_app before (none of the hashes match what's on github). I just tried `heroku create` from the sample_app directory, and then `git push heroku master`, and I get the same error. Here is the [URL](http://quiet-sands-7291.herokuapp.com).

Comment: This is the error message I get, to be more precise: 


Creating quiet-sands-7291... done, region is us
http://quiet-sands-7291.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:quiet-sands-7291.git
jeffrey-benners-macbook:sample_app Jeffrey$ git push heroku master

 !  No such app as sample_app.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Thank you @fontno! Starting with everything copied into a new directory worked. I don't want to trouble you for more, but is there possibly a place where I could read about what was wrong, and how this resolved the issue?

Comment: No problem, glad it worked. You should start with really learning git inside and out. Here is the [git book](http://git-scm.com/book). Also chapter one of the tutorial book your following has more info about all the commands in my post. And read the developer docs on Heroku, there are many things to learn. Good luck

Answer (score 8):

I just came across the same problem. I did the following:

```
cd .git
vim config
```

removed all lines referencing Heroku

```
cd ..
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

... And voila, it worked.

Hoped this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Well, instead of creating app from scratch i did `heroku git:remote -a myappname`

Comment: Just to add, `vim config` means you open a text editor and remove the heroku referencing lines. In my case it was `subl config`.

Answer (score 0):

I had no idea why, but stopping running **foreman** in my local machine allowed a push to heroku master... Could be coincidence :|