# Pushing the code on Heroku Django

Tags: python, django, git, ubuntu, heroku

I'm following [this link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django) for uploading my app on heroku. Earlier I was facing `git push heroku master Permission denied (publickey).` error, but I resolved it by adding SSH keys of my github account to heroku using `heroku keys:add`. Now I'm facing an error that when I push data into heroku using `git push heroku master` , it says

```
No such app as still-bastion-1881.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Now, Where is the problem lying? I'm using ubuntu.

Comment: Try `git push --verbose heroku master`. Also, have you tried using `heroku push`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not read from remote repository when pushing to Heroku (Rails Tutorial 5)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752415/could-not-read-from-remote-repository-when-pushing-to-heroku-rails-tutorial-5)

Comment: Thanks. The possible duplicate answer worked..

Comment: Now, when I'm pushing the data, an error pops up which says `Downloading/unpacking PAM==0.4.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
         Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PAM==0.4.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (from versions: 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3)
       No distributions matching the version for PAM==0.4.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
       Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app`

Comment: What's being reported there is accurate. There's no verison 0.4.2 of PAM on PyPI. Is the PAM you reference a private package of your own?